# SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules when done on terminal

Tags: php, soap

I'm getting this error: SOAP-ERROR: Encoding: Violation of encoding rules

But it **works fine when run from my web app**, and fails when I try and run it via a script that I intend to run by cron.

Here is my request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns1="http://clients.xxxxxxxxx.com/api/0_5" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns1:GetClients>
            <ns1:Request>
                <ns1:SourceCredentials>
                    <ns1:SourceName>xxxxxxxxx</ns1:SourceName>
                    <ns1:Password>xxxxxxxxxx</ns1:Password>
                    <ns1:SiteIDs><ns1:int>xxx</ns1:int></ns1:SiteIDs>
                </ns1:SourceCredentials>
                <ns1:UserCredentials>
                    <ns1:Username>xxxxxxxx</ns1:Username>
                    <ns1:Password>xxxxxxxx</ns1:Password>
                    <ns1:SiteIDs>
                        <ns1:int>xxx</ns1:int>
                    </ns1:SiteIDs>
                </ns1:UserCredentials>
            </ns1:Request>
        </ns1:GetClients>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Since the error message mentions encoding, what encoding is being used in the webapp and the script?

Comment: I'm running into this same issue...have you made any headway on this?

Comment: I have same issue. @RobLester, how did you solve this?